# View Custom perspective when breakpoint is triggered

Tags: eclipse

I have created a custom debug perspective and I want it to open automatically when a breakpoint is triggered. At the moment, the default debug perspective opens and I have to keep switching to my preferred one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Eclipse, go to **Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Perspectives**.
2. In the **Application Types/Launchers** box, expand the **Java Application** item and select **Eclipse JDT Launcher**.
3. In the **Debug** dropdown to the right, select your custom debug perspective.
4. Click **OK**.